# How can I create a button in an administration module which calls an api request?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I want to extend an administration module with a button base component. On click on this button it should call an api request. How can I reach this?
More precisely I have a button base component in the administration and want to add an action to it. Do I need a service or a controller or neither of them? How can I add an action to  my button to call the desired method?
I don't know and I didn't find something like that in the shopware documentation.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please, study the [documentation on Vue](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html). This is very basic knowledge required to do anything with Vue and isn't Shopware specific at all.

Going to assume you mean a request to any admin api endpoint, except the repository operations which you should [inject and use the `repositoryFactory` service for](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/using-data-handling).

```js
const initContainer = Shopware.Application.getContainer('init');
const headers = {
    Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${Shopware.Service(
        'loginService'
    ).getToken()}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};

const endpoint = 'api/some/endpoint';
initContainer.httpClient.get(endpoint, { headers });
initContainer.httpClient.post(endpoint, { someParam: true }, { headers });
initContainer.httpClient.patch(endpoint, { someParam: true }, { headers });
initContainer.httpClient.delete(endpoint, { data: { id: '...' }, headers });
```

That code would be part of a [method that is called on the click event of an element](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html).